# macro extract defined function name

Tags: function, julia, metaprogramming

I have two functions

```
funcA(x::AbstractMatrix;subd=nothing)=funcA(x[1,:],x[2,:],subd) # format transformer
funcA(a::AbstractVector,b::AbstractVector;subd=nothing)
    babalah
end
```

and

```
funcB(x::AbstractMatrix)=funcB(x[1,:],x[2,:]) # format transformer
funcB(a::AbstractVector,b::AbstractVector)
    babalah
end
```

I wish a macro can easily help me to add the "format transformer" automatically to the funcA and funcB and it can add arguments.
What should I do?

Comment: Why not just have `formattransformer(f, x::AbstractMatrix; kwargs...) = f(x[1, :], x[2, :]; kwargs...)`?

Comment: Proposing anything that could make more sense than what @phipsgabler  wrote would require a more detailed example from your side.

Comment: @PrzemyslawSzufel Just watched your JuliaCon talk... great King Crimson plug in the background :D

Comment: @phipsgabler it is an LP, first German press. over 50yo, not a plug ;-)

Comment: @phipsgabler that sounds reasonable...,new to julia, THANKS!